# Having trouble in C++ Creating vector of pointers or map of Pointer values

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, vector, boost

To give some context, I am trying to create a map or a vector that looks like either of these:
I have tried both, and can't seem to get it working.

```
vector<Player*,Player*> regionOwners; 
map<int, vector<Player*>> regionOwners;
```

Essentially I have regions in a game that correspond to integer values (0-10) 
Most regions can only have 1 owner (the player), however certain ones can also have 2 owners. 
This is the reason I want to have a vector, so that I can go regionOwners[regionNumber][0] or regionOwners[regionNumber][1] and either access a playerObject or a nullptr. If possible, I want to set the vector size to a max of 2.

I essentially want to store examples like this:

```
1 --> [PlayerPtr*]
2 --> [Player1Ptr*, Player2Ptr*]
3 --> [nullptr, nullptr]
4 --> [nullptr]
5 --> [Player1Ptr*, nullptr]
6 --> [nullptr, Player1Ptr*]
```

I cant seem to initialize my vector or map with nullptrs to indicate that the region does not have an owner.

```
for(int i=0; i< gameMap->getVertexCount(); i++) {
    if(gameMap->getVertex(i)->getData() == "outer") {
        regionOwners[i].push_back({nullptr , nullptr}); // vector style
    }
    else if (gameMap->getVertex(i)->getData() == "inner") {
        regionOwners.insert({i, {nullptr}});
    }
 }
```

I have tried all variations of maps and vectors. Im stumped.

```
        regionOwners[i]= {nullptr , nullptr}; // vector
        regionOwners.insert({nullptr, nullptr}); // vector
        map<int,vector<Player*>> something;
        something.insert(i, {nullptr, nullptr});
        regionOwners[i].push_back({nullptr , nullptr}); 
        regionOwners.push_back(i ,{nullptr , nullptr});
```

I was wondering what suggestions anyone has on how to solve my issue, as I know I'm likely going about this wrong. I thought of using a vector of a linkedlist so that I could just go from one node of a Player to the other once I have resolved the region. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should use `new Player()` instead of `nullptr`, it will cause various problems the moment you try to access a pointer that is assigned as `nullptr`...

Comment: `vector<Player*,Player*>` isn't a valid vector instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this

```
vector<Player*,Player*> regionOwners;
```

can't work as you intend it. `std::vector` stores scalar entries (and the second template argument is an allocator which you probably don't want to specify right now), so this declaration will be rejected by the compiler.

> If possible, I want to set the vector size to a max of 2

That makes it a `std::pair`, not a `std::vector`. You can try one of these:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Player*, Player*>> regionOwnersVec;
std::map<int, std::pair<Player*, Player*>> regionOwnersMap;
```

Now you can use them e.g. like the following.

```
// allocates memory if necessary:
regionOwnersVec.push_back({nullptr, nullptr});

// ... or set some predefined size, which allocates and default-initializes:
regionOwnersVec.resize(42);

// ... which enables indexing the vector:
regionOwnersVec[10] = {nullptr, nullptr};
```

Or alternatively for the `std::map` instance,

```
regionOwnerMap[10] = {nullptr, nullptr};
```

As a side note, if you want the container to *own* the instances, prefer `std::unique_ptr` together with `std::make_unique` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: If I make it a pair though, won't one value (Player) map to the other?

Comment: A pair is just two values. They are tied together, but that's somewhat true for any container, too. Also, the `std::pair::second` can be `nullptr` such that there is no such "mapping".

Comment: Ended up making a std::vector<std::pair<Player*, Player*>> regionOwnersVec;
like you said. Works the way i need it to. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::array<Player*, 2>>
```

will work as you wanted, i.e. it only allows at most 2 region owners and you can use double `operator[]`:

```
std::vector<std::array<Player*, 2>> regionOwners (11, {nullptr, nullptr});
if(regionOwners[5][1]) {
    //blahblah
}
```

For convienience, you can create a name alias:

```
using RegionOwners = std::vector<std::array<Player*, 2>>;
RegionOwners regionOwners (11, {nullptr, nullptr});
```

Comment: I tried that, but whenever I try to do : regionOwners[region][0] i get:

   Type 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::array<Player *, 2>, 
   std::__1::allocator<std::__1::array<Player *, 2> > >::value_type' (aka 
   'std::__1::array<Player *, 2>') does not provide a subscript operator